# Continuous Integration for Windows Phone 7/8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, jenkins, windows-phone, continuous-integration

I have searched googles and stack overflow searching for this kind of information, but without any luck.

What I need to do, is to prepare some continuous integration server for our WP7/WP8 applications.

We need to do some unit test, and UI tests on those application, possibly on both WP7 and WP8 platforms.

Hopefully I would like to use **Jenkins+Git+msbuild** configuration under **Windows 8 x64 Profesional**.

- Have anybody tried it?
- Is it even possible?
- Do you use real devices or emulator?
- If it cannot be done with jenkins, what are the other options?

Answer (score 2):

I've done it with TFS (Both Visual Studio online and on premise) and I can see no reason that it wouldn't work with Jenkins though. (Which I've previously used for other project types.)

However, the automated testing of UI is not straight forward, especially on WP7.

UI testing becomes much easier with the automated options available under WPA8.1
For 7 & 8 you could try https://github.com/Expensify/WindowsPhoneTestFramework

Be aware that you can't run the emulator on a server so UI testing there is probably not an option.

I normally run two lots of unit and integration tests.
I run "proper" unit tests in a PCL with NUnit or MSTest.
I'll run anything that needs phone integration in a test on device with https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPToolkitTestFx/